# Configuring Scrapy to import Custom classes in an IDE

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

When attempting to convert a Selenium based scraping project to Scrapy, I've run into an issue when setting up Scrapy in the Pycharm IDE. The question boils down to **how do I get a Scrapy Spider class to point to a custom Python class defined somewhere else in a project?** Essentially the following simple class yields this error when calling `scrapy list`. Note that this happens with pandas if I do not pip install it again from within Scrapy subdirectory.

*Error:*

```
File "C:\PycharmProject\scrapers\spi
ders\SomeSpider.py", line 2, in <module>
    from classfile import MyCustomClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyCustomClass'
```

*Simple Class*

```
import scrapy
from classfile import MyCustomClass

class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    
    def parse(self, response):
        #Do something with MyCustomClass
```

Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Set up a new project in Pycharm
2. Install pandas and scrapy in the project venv
3. In the Pycharm terminal (pointed project directory root), type `scrapy startproject scrapers`
4. Create SomeSpider class in root/scrapers/spiders folder
5. Create Custom dataclass in project root directory

What am I missing? How do I make my Spider aware of the root directory?

Comment: i am not using pycharm but tried and i couldn't  reproduce the error sorry :(

Comment: try adding a `.` in front of classfile.  Like `from .classfile import MyCustomClass`